# Julia 1.1 Create a grid (array of points in a grid)

Tags: grid, julia

Using Julia 1.1, I want to create a grid of points based on a vector of ranges

When using this code, it gives me a list of such points

```
u = [[i j ] for i in -1:0.5:1, j in -1:0.5:1]
[u...]
```

However, I am unable to develop a more generic approach that would create such a vector of multidimensional points when given an array of ranges

For example, develop a createGrid function that would take a Vector of n ranges as argument and output a list of all the points.

```
createGrid([1.:0.5:0., 1.:0.5:0., 1.:0.5:0.])
```

that would output:

```
27-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 [-1.0 -1.0 -1.0]
 [-0.5 -1.0 -1.0]
 [0.0 -1.0 -1.0] 
 [-1.0 -0.5 -1.0]
 [-0.5 -0.5 -1.0]
 [0.0 -0.5 -1.0] 
 [-1.0 0.0 -1.0] 
 [-0.5 0.0 -1.0] 
 [0.0 0.0 -1.0]  
 [-1.0 -1.0 -0.5]
 [-0.5 -1.0 -0.5]
 [0.0 -1.0 -0.5] 
 [-1.0 -0.5 -0.5]
 ⋮
```

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to materialize the grid? Can't you just let the grid remain implicitly defined by the collection of ranges?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `Iterators.product`. It doesn't create the `Array`s, but creates an object you can iterate over to get each new element of the grid as a `Tuple` (which is actually usually what you want).

```
julia> p = Iterators.product(-1.:0.5:0., -1.:0.5:0., -1.:0.5:0.);
julia> println.(p);
(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
(-0.5, -1.0, -1.0)
(0.0, -1.0, -1.0)
(-1.0, -0.5, -1.0)
(-0.5, -0.5, -1.0)
(0.0, -0.5, -1.0)
(-1.0, 0.0, -1.0)
⋮
```

Comment: How to get elements of p afterwards? p[1] does not seem to work

Answer (score 4):

I would use:

```
using GeometryTypes
grid(ranges::NTuple{N, <: AbstractRange}) where N = Point.(Iterators.product(ranges...))
p = grid((-1.:0.5:0.0, -1.:0.5:0.0))
```

By using an NTuple instead of a Vector of ranges, this methods becomes type stable (the return type gets inferred as e.g `Vector{Point{2, Float64}}`).
Also, using Points is more efficient than `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`, has C-compatible layout and has all the operations defined which you need for points...
As a bonus, it directly plots in Makie / Plots as points :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the excellent answer above, if you do want a vector-of-vectors you can `collect` each of the tuples into a vector, and then call `vec` to flatten this array-of-vectors into a vector-of-vectors

```
julia> p = Iterators.product(-1.0:0.5:0.0, -1.0:0.5:0.0, -1.0:0.5:0.0);

julia> collect.(p)
3×3×3 Array{Array{Float64,1},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]  [-1.0, -0.5, -1.0]  [-1.0, 0.0, -1.0]
 [-0.5, -1.0, -1.0]  [-0.5, -0.5, -1.0]  [-0.5, 0.0, -1.0]
 [0.0, -1.0, -1.0]   [0.0, -0.5, -1.0]   [0.0, 0.0, -1.0]

[:, :, 2] =
 [-1.0, -1.0, -0.5]  [-1.0, -0.5, -0.5]  [-1.0, 0.0, -0.5]
 [-0.5, -1.0, -0.5]  [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]  [-0.5, 0.0, -0.5]
 [0.0, -1.0, -0.5]   [0.0, -0.5, -0.5]   [0.0, 0.0, -0.5]

[:, :, 3] =
 [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0]  [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]  [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 [-0.5, -1.0, 0.0]  [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0]  [-0.5, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.0, -1.0, 0.0]   [0.0, -0.5, 0.0]   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

julia> vec(collect.(p))
27-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
 [-0.5, -1.0, -1.0]
 [0.0, -1.0, -1.0]
 [-1.0, -0.5, -1.0]
 [-0.5, -0.5, -1.0]
 [0.0, -0.5, -1.0]
 [-1.0, 0.0, -1.0]
 ⋮
```